# OS X install libcurl / Solr installation

Tags: php, curl, solr

I set up the default Apache Server with PHP on OS X Yosemite, installed pear, installed Solr with brew (`brew install solr`) and am now trying to install the Solr extension for PHP with PECL using

```
pecl install solr
```

This gives me the error

```
configure: error: Please reinstall the libcurl distribution -
    easy.h should be in <curl-dir>/include/curl/
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/solr/configure --enable-solr-debug=no --with-curl=/usr --with-libxml-dir=/usr' failed
```

However, the `curl` command is available in Terminal. Did I give the wrong path when asked during the installation

```
Enable Solr Debugging (Compiles solr in debug mode) [no] : 
libcURL install prefix [/usr] : 
libxml2 install prefix [/usr] :
```

and, if yes, how do I find the right path? Or do I need to install curl again and, if yes, what is the best way and can I do this using homebrew?

I will probably get the same problem with libxml2, won't I?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Okay, well I found the library in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/curl`. But now during the make process I get the error `In file included from /private/tmp/pear/install/solr/php_solr.c:23:
/private/tmp/pear/install/solr/php_solr.h:28:10: fatal error: 'main/php.h' file not found`

Comment: I needed to install OS X developer tools: `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Your answer also helped me. I suggest you post your comment as an answer so others will have a better chance of seeing it!

Comment: That's great news Andrew. I followed your advice and added the comment as an answer as well!

Answer (score 4):

The problem was solved by installing the OS X developer tools.

You can do so via Terminal by executing

```
xcode-select --install
```

I hope this may help somebody having the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful to get past the initial error: https://chowdera.com/2020/11/202011132244396707.html

Sumamry:

brew install curl

brew install libxml2

brew install openssl

brew install libidn2

brew install brotli

export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libidn2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/brotli/lib"

pecl install solr

inputs at pause:

1. yes
2. /usr/local/opt/curl
3. /usr/local/opt/libxml2

hopefully at this point you see Build process completed successfully